# Object of class .. could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I made my first class and I'm having trouble converting the objects back into strings.

```
class Cryption
{
    var $data;
    var $salt;

function __construct($data, $salt)
{
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->salt = $salt;
}

function sha512()
{
    $sodium = 'Na';
    return hash_hmac("sha512", $this->data . $this->salt, $sodium);
}

function encrypt()
{
    $salt = substr(sha512(($this->key), 'brownies'), 0, 30);
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $this->data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($salt)));
}
```

When I use it:

```
$password = new Cryption(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password'])), 'pepper');
$password->sha512();
```

It says 'PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Cryption could not be converted to string'

I don't really know how to get it back into a string.  May someone please help me?

Thank you.

Edit:

```
<?php
require("config.php");
include("includes/cryption/cryption.php");

$username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
$password = new Cryption(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password'])), 'pepper'); //use a different salt next time such as a special salt for each user
$password->sha512();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `administrators` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {
    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = array(
            'id' => $row[0],
            'username' => $row[1],
            'password' => $row[2]
        );
        $userid = new Cryption($_SESSION['user']['id'], 'kkfishing');
        $session = new Cryption($_SESSION['user']['username'], 'kkfishing');
        $validated = new Cryption($_SESSION['user']['password'], 'kkfishing');

        setcookie("uniqueid", $userid->encrypt(), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/"); //100 days
        setcookie("kksessionid", $session->encrypt(), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");
        setcookie("kkuserid", $validated->encrypt(), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");//disguised cookie name
    }
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = $row[0];
    echo '1'; //true
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo '0'; //false
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: The code you shown us cannot return that error. You use it as a string somewhere else.

Comment: Can you post the whole code? This snippet can't produce that exception.

Comment: @Kyle: and which line does error point to? If you want your issue to be solved - give **ALL THE POSSIBLE INFORMATION**. No one here is interesting in playing jeopardy with you asking about details.

Comment: I'm sorry Zerk. Andreas just pointed out the snippet on which the error lies on.

Comment: @Kyle: so did I, but I removed my answer, since I was later. Anyway, dude, next time specify the **related** code and specify the **exact line** you have issues with.

Comment: @zerk I shall do that, thank you for the information I will use it for future reference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at this lines:

```
$password->sha512();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `administrators` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
```

`$password` is an object. It should be:

```
$pw = $password->sha512();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `administrators` WHERE username='$username' and password='$pw'");
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea it was that.  This also helps me with the other variables set as objects too. Thanks a lot Andreas. :)

Comment: I had no idea that's how you solve the object problems.  You're right it pointed me where to look it's just I wasn't sure what to do about object problems.  If it was the class or if it was the other part, I was confused.

Answer (score 5):

The same error can be encountered when initializing the constructor variable in a wrong way like below:

```
 function __construct($data, $salt)
{
    $this->$data = $data; //mistakenly using $ (dollar) sign after `$this->`
    $this->$salt = $salt;
}
```

Where the correct way of initializing is:

```
function __construct($data, $salt)
{
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->salt = $salt;
}
```

Comment: this is not the case for this problem OP posted, but i faced the same error when was initializing in the same manner. hope it would save time for someone :)