# PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in wp

Tags: php, string

**Problem**

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/faceboo2/netbusinesseurope.com/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1249

```
$string = preg_replace( '/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]/', '', $string );
```

PHP version = 7.0.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object of class .. could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156440/object-of-class-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Comment: Well, `$string` does _not_ contain a string as expected, but an error message. The code apparently is not really robust...

Answer (score 0):

Any time you get a "could not be converted to string" error, it's because you're trying to use something that isn't a string in a context where a string is expected. PHP will try to convert whatever it is, but an object can't be converted unless it has a `__toString` method.

In your case, `$string` appears to be a `WP_Error` object. Something may have gone wrong before that line, because `$string` seems like an odd thing to call that object, but based on [the Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error), you should be able to get the actual error message string with:

```
$message = $string->get_error_message()
```

Then you can do string stuff with it.